# Multipying 3 dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

This is a homework question. I'm not asking for the full answer just some tips to keep moving along. I've been working on this for way to long. I'm multiplying the 3 dimensional array contains a list of people and the qty of tools they are buying I'm multiplying the item qty by an array of prices. The problem I'm having is that all three arrays are giving the same total instead of multipying each by a different factor. I've tried a few different approaches. I figured I need to use a while statement or if else to multiply each price to it's $key=>$value, but can't seem to get it to work.

[Homework Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fw1Up.png)

```
  <?php
               $names = array(array( 'Name' => 'Tom',
                                     'Hammers' => 3,
                                     'Saws' => 2,
                                     'Drills' => 2
                                    ),
                       array( 'Name' => 'Sue',
                                     'Hammers' => 2,
                                     'Saws' => 3,
                                     'Drills' => 2
                             ),
                       array( 'Name' => 'Steve',
                              'Hammers' => 2,
                              'Saws' => 2,
                              'Drills' =>2
                             )
                      );

               $prices = array('Hammers'=>3.00,'Saws'=>2.50,'Drills'=>3.25);

               for($array=0;$array<count($names);$array++){
                    foreach($names[$array] as $key=>$value)
                    {

                        $total= $names[0]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
                        $total= $names[1]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
                        $total= $names[2]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
                        echo $key." = ".$value. "total".$total.'<br>';

                     }

                   }


              ?>
```

Comment: This is the result I get when I execute the code.                                                                                                                     Name = Tomtotal9
Hammers = 3total9
Saws = 2total9
Drills = 2total9
Name = Suetotal9
Hammers = 2total9
Saws = 3total9
Drills = 2total9
Name = Stevetotal9
Hammers = 2total9
Saws = 2total9
Drills = 2total9

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the full solution, right?
Well, you are just summing the Hammers value. How about you just do a foreach in your `$names` and calculate the `$total` inside it, using the `$prices` array. No nested `for`s. There is no need for that.

Hope I was helpful and if you need some code, just comment that I'll edit this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this simple script should do it?

```
    $total_overall = 0.0;

    foreach($names as $name) {

        $total_hammers = $name["Hammers"] * $prices["Hammers"];
        $total_saws = $name["Saws"] * $prices["Saws"];
        $total_drills = $name["Drills"] * $prices["Drills"];

        // print single prices sums if you want ...

        $total_for_person = $total_hammers + $total_saws + $total_drills;

        $total_overall += $total_for_person;

        echo "Total for person ". $name["Name"]." = ".$total_for_person;

    }

// print total overall if you want ...
```

Comment: I was looking for the total of all items in each array, but I also wanted to find the total of each item. So the answer would look like this. Tom hammer total = $9, Saw total = $5, and Drill total = $6.50. That's why my code looks the way it does above. The problem I was having is it would say tom=9 hammers=9 saws =9 drills=9. Then it would loop to Sue and give her the same answers. When they have different item qty.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons you're getting the same number repeatedly. First, when you do this:

```
$total= $names[0]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
$total= $names[1]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
$total= $names[2]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
```

You're assigning a value to `$total` three times. Each time you assign to `$total`, you overwrite the previous value. So these three lines have the same effect as:

```
$total= $names[2]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
```

The second problem is that you're always calculating the total for Hammers, rather than calculating the total for the current type of item.

---

One thing that you can use to your advantage with this problem is that except for `'Name'`, `$prices` has the same keys as each of the arrays in `$names`. This means you can calculate each item total for each person using `$value * $prices[$key]`, like this:

```
for ($array=0; $array < count($names); $array++) {
    foreach($names[$array] as $key => $value) {
        $total = $value * $prices[$key];
        echo $key." = ".$value. "total".$total.'<br>';
     }
}
```

The only problem with this is that you'll try to calculate a total for `Name`, which obviously doesn't need one, and doesn't have a value in `$prices`. That should be fairly easy for you to clean up with an `if`, though.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here

```
$total= $names[0]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
$total= $names[1]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
$total= $names[2]["Hammers"] * $prices['Hammers'];
echo $key." = ".$value. "total".$total.'<br>';
```

Comment: I think you are gonna want `+=` on the second two equations.

Comment: What is the problem. How to fix it. Why.. etc... sorry but otherwise this isn't much helpful answer.

Comment: So would you suggest the multiply() or how else am I suppose to multiply each item qty by the price?